# NodeJS Line reader library should call sync instead of async

Tags: node.js

is there a ways to make the line reader synchronous?

```
const lineReader = require('line-reader');
const test = await lineReader.eachLine(absoluteFullFilePath, cb);
```

This doesnt work for me. I dont understand how this can be made synchronous.

Comment: This library, as it says in the documentation, is async; use fs.readFileSync instead.
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options

Comment: thx can you please write an answer so i can check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line Reader library is Asynchronous by it's implementation. You can use Node.js own fs.readFileSync() instead.

```
// Node.js program to demonstrate the 
// fs.readFileSync() method 

// Include fs module 
const fs = require('fs'); 

// Calling the readFileSync() method 
// to read 'input.txt' file 
const data = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt', 
            {encoding:'utf8', flag:'r'}); 

// Display the file data 
console.log(data);
```